# loop in python for two text files

Tags: python

this is my first time here and i wish i get your help.
i'm new to python and i need your help

i have two .txt files
here an Example
file1.txt

```
customer1.com
customer2.com
customer3.com
customer4.com
customer5.com
customer6.com
customer7.com
customer8.com
customer9.com
```

file2.txt

```
service1
service2
service3
```

i want to loop the file2.txt on the file1.txt =>
like the following example

```
customer1.com/service1
customer1.com/service2  
customer1.com/service3

customer2.com/service1
customer2.com/service2  
customer2.com/service3

customer3.com/service1
customer3.com/service2  
customer3.com/service3
```

AND GOES ON  TILL  file1.txt is done.

also i need to make IF statment 
for example let's say the customer number3 has the service number 2 (file found i mean)

customer3.com/service2 [service found]

i need the loop for customer3 to stop looking for services and save the output (customer3.com/service2) in a new file called file3.txt
and the loop go on with other customers and every customer has the service found, the output save in file3.txt

i hope you understand what i mean. 
thanks.

Comment: You want to perform a cartesian product on two lists, and a stop condition on a criteria.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `itertools.product` to get a cartesian product of the lines from each file to get every URL combination:

```
from itertools import product

with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2, open(
    "file3.txt", mode="w"
) as out:
    for x, y in product(f1, f2):
        out.write("%s/%s\n" % (x.strip(), y.strip()))
```

*file3.txt*

```
customer1.com/service1
customer1.com/service2
customer1.com/service3
customer2.com/service1
customer2.com/service2
customer2.com/service3
customer3.com/service1
customer3.com/service2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop task is easy. you need to read every file and to save data as list. then write a file with that loop order. See example. But I do not understand that black line and that *service found* logic. Is to general. Be more specific.

Example:

```
list1, list2 = [], []

with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1:
    line = f1.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.strip()
        list1.append(line)
        line = f1.readline()
with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    line = f2.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.strip()
        list2.append(line)
        line = f2.readline()
with open("file3.txt", "w") as f3:
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            f3.write(f"{i}/{j}\n")
        f3.write("\n") # just for that black line
```

Comment: i'm working on project to find a word "FinedMe" in text file. 
for example:

customer1.com/service1.txt
customer1.com/service2.txt
customer1.com/service3.txt

customer2.com/service1.txt
customer2.com/service2.txt
customer2.com/service3.txt


customer3.com/service1.txt
customer3.com/service2.txt
customer3.com/service3.txt


let's say the word in the following Paths for example

customer3.com/service2.txt   [word found]
customer1.com/service3.txt   [word found]
customer2.com/service1.txt   [word found]

that's why i was looking also for IF statement.
you got me ?

Comment: @Deller So you want to found a word in all files? Like search word in all files? Is hard to get it because I do not understand general explanation in this case. Hit me with real example. Like just 1-2 examples from real problem...

Comment: i will make a new topic and get back to you to answer there. 
thank you so much for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read line by line and use the accordingly.

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
lines1 = file1.readlines()
lines2 = file2.readlines()
for line_from_1 in lines1:
    for line_from_2 in lines2:
        print(line_from_1 + '/' + line_from_2)
```